# Multiple trigger AlarmManager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

is that posible to trigger one AlarmManager more than once ( not only 1:00 or 4:00 or 10:00 ), i mean, if i had 1 AlarmManager and could i execute the AlarmManager every 1:00,  4:00, 10:00 ? or is there other suggestion ?

if yes could you explain with code ?

this is my code and this just execute only every 12:00

```
public static void InitLoggingService(Context context) {
    boolean         bolLoggingServiceState  =   UtilitiesPreferences.GetLoggingServiceState(context);
    Intent          _Intent                 =   new Intent(context, ServiceMain.class);
    Intent          SaveFileIntent          =   new Intent(context, ServiceLogger.class);
    PendingIntent   SaveFilePending         =   PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, SaveFileIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager    _AlarmManager           =   (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar        _Calendar               =   Calendar.getInstance();

    _Calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);

    if (bolLoggingServiceState == true){
        context.startService(_Intent);
        _AlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, _Calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, SaveFilePending);
    }else{
        context.stopService(_Intent);
        InitStarterService(context);
        _AlarmManager.cancel(SaveFilePending);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is very much possible.It seems i don't need to tell u about writing services and receiver,my guess from above code is that u have already done it. I will tell u the logic to achieve what u want.

Few of the changes you need to do is call the `alarmmanager` every time it fires i.e cancel the previous alarm and start a new one.In other words configure the alarm to execute only once.So every time your service gets called start a new alarm

Make a local db on mobile.Save the intervals at which u want to execute the alarm like 1,4,10 .Also in the same table put a field that would notify you about which interval was last executed. Then every time u make a new alarm call read from db the interval and execute accordingly.